# Best software for taking photos when motion is detected in a camera stream?

Tags: video, vlc, webcam, camera

I'm searching for a Linux friendly software for security cameras, I'm using Mint Victoria. I need a software that can read both webcams and IP network cameras without being too complex to use.

Something simple that can detect motion and take photos(screenshots) of the stream when such motion is detected, even short videos is a start. But saving all data and constantly recording takes too much space and those videos quickly cross gigabytes of size for me.

Do you think Motion could do that, or maybe VLC(I got access to the camera streams both IP and webcam but I'm not sure if VLC is able to detect motion)

Comment: Mint is off topic here.

Answer (score 2):

`motion` can indeed do that.

It's not the easiest s/w to set up - you must do it by editing the config file - but you can have it take a certain number of pictures, or a video clip, or both.

I have used it to watch a bird nest where the birds came and went quickly and infrequently, to find out what kind of birds they were. I used an old Android tablet for the camera.

Comment: Could you provide any documentation on setting it up to do what I wish? I'm not sure where to look for the newest version.

Comment: The config file is well commented. Since I don't know what you want it to do, you should probably ask another question. However, I now see your question is off topic here, so I suggest you ask at the Unix and Linux stack, where Mint is on-topic.